# NLTK Tagging specific words

Tags: python, nltk

I'm new to NTLK and Python overall. I understand you can insert a sentence and have all the words tagged to a part of speech, but i'm trying to figure out how to tag for a specific part of speech. For example, I want to only tag nouns and verbs, how would I go about doing that? This is probably a dumb question but I've been researching for a bit and still am very confused. I'd be great if I could get a few lines of code that I can edit to tag for specific parts of speech.

Comment: Have you tried following some tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
nltk.download('punkt')

text = word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(text)
print(tagged)
verbs_nouns = [w[0] for w in tagged if w[1]=='VP' or w[1]=='NN']
print(verbs_nouns)
```

in that case just filter your tagged list for whatever parts you'd like.

https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html

Comment: How would I tag for specific part(s) of speech? I want to tag for only nouns or verbs.